# How does this array with this indexing work? K&R exercise

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am reading K&R, currently on chapter 1. After reading a section and trying to solve the problems, I like to check out for other solutions online just see different methods to tackle the same problem.

Exercise 1-14 says that we need to print an histogram of the frequencies of different characters in its input. This solution I found only takes into consideration alphabet characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 122
#define MIN 97
#define DIFF 32

int main(){
  int c = EOF;
  int i, j;
  int array[MAX - MIN];
  printf("%d  ", MAX - MIN);

  for (i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++){
    array[i] = 0;
    printf("%d  ", i);
  }

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c >= MIN)
    ++array[c];
    else {
      ++array[c + DIFF];
    }
  }

  for (i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++){
    printf("|%c%c|", i - DIFF, i);
    for (j = 1; j <= array[i]; j++){
      putchar('*');
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

While I understand the logic behind this code, I don't understand how or why the `array[]` array works. When declaring the array, the size of it is `25 (MAX - MIN).` This array should be indexed from 0 to 24. However during the first loop, the array is indexed using values from `97` to `122`. But how is it possible to access the array if the indexing starts from a value much larger? Shouldn't the loop be

```
for (i = 0, i < MAX - MIN; i++)
```

It makes no sense to me how the array could be indexed from

```
array[97] ... array[122]
```

**EDIT:**

I added `printf("%d  ", MAX - MIN);` and `printf("%d  ", i);` in the first loop myself to try to see if it in fact was indexing the array from `97` onwards.

Comment: `int array[MAX - MIN];` should be `int array[MAX - MIN + 1];`

Comment: I know, this assumes there are only 25 letters in the alphabet, so first bug I found. Still don't understand why the rest of the loop works though and why am I not getting warnings or segmentation faults @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Basically,  Array access is not checked for array size in C. segmentation faults may or may not occur.

Comment: @ch15 it's called "undefined bahaviour" (Google that term). You don't necessarily get a segfault when you access an array out of bounds.

Comment: @MichaelWalz so technically speaking, I could've declared an array of size 1, run a for loop 26 times, indexing the array for any 26 consecutive values and it still would work? I know this is not good code whatsoever, but would it work like this one? Is the code I posted therefore wrong? Should the for loop be as the one I posted at the bottom?

Comment: @ch15 yes it _could_ appear to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int array[MAX - MIN];
```

Here, size of array is `25` because `197-97 = 25`.

```
 for (i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++){
    array[i] = 0;
```

Here, index of `array[i]` is out of bound because size of array is `25` and value and `MIN` is `97`.

Also, `++array[c];` and  `j <= array[i];` is undefined because out of bound.

GCC compiler generated warning:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:14:10: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     array[i] = 0;
          ^
source_file.c:20:12: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     ++array[c];
            ^
source_file.c:20:12: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
source_file.c:28:27: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     for (j = 1; j <= array[i]; j++){
                           ^
```

**C11 J.2 Undefined behavior**

> - Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an integer type produces a result that points just beyond
>     the array object and is used as the operand of a unary *operator that
>     is evaluated (6.5.6).
> - An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>     accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>     `a[1][7]` given the declaration int `a[4][5])` (6.5.6).

Comment: Nice answer, it seems that it agrees with mine (check it if you have time please). How did you manage to get GCC spit out these warnings?

Comment: I am getting an error while trying to compile it online. I tried the OP's code in Wandbox, with `-Wall -Wextra` and didn't get any warning(s)...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the for loop is accessing the array out of bounds, invoking *Undefined Behavior*, which means that your program may crash or not.

`MAX - MIN` gives 25 and you access the array with indices in [97, 122], which is definetely wrong.

Similarly, `++array[c]` and `for (j = 1; j <= array[i]; j++)` invoke Undefined Behavior as well, since they go out of bounds too.

PS: You need to declare your array with a size of `MAX - MIN + 1`, since the english alphabet has 26 letters.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that was the first thing I though when I saw the array declaration (25 letters), so I tried to run it expecting to have warnings or not compile at all, but it did work, and at least with the few test cases I tried it was always correct, thus why I asked this question. Thanks for your response anyway, quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is `no boundary checking in C` for arrays, it is the responsibility of the programmer to take care of it.

so when you declare an array as

```
int array[ MAX - MIN ] ;
```

you are not restricted to use only `sizeof( int ) * (MAX - MIN)` but then if you don't use within this range behavior is quite erratic.

there are other programming languages that do enforce array boundary check but not c, unless of course it goes through rigorous compilation steps including string warning checks.

so in this case even though the program works it is not correct.

perhaps the bottom line to understand is

*"Working code may not always be a correct code"*